# Wicket 6.18 AjaxEventBehavior("onkeypress") when getPrecondition return false

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket-6

i'm trying to add an AjaxEventBehavior("onkeypress") to a TextField, i'm doing in this way

```
TextField<String> input = new TextField<String>("input");
    input.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    input.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onkeypress") {

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            Panel.this.info("hello!");
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
            super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

            attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener(){
                public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
                    return "if (Wicket.Event.keyCode(attrs.event)  == 13) " +
                            " { return true; } " +
                            "else { return false; }";
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

When i press Enter (keyCode==13) inside the input my feedbackpanel show's hello! but when i press another key nothing happen the Wicket Ajax Debug get the INFO: "Ajax request stopped because of precondition check" my ajaxIndicator starts and never stop.

I have a application.js with this

```
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/before',showBusysign);
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/success',hideBusysign);
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/failure',hideBusysign);
}

function hideBusysign() {
    document.getElementById('busyIndicator').style.display = 'none';
    hideMask();
}

function showBusysign() {
    document.getElementById('busyIndicator').src = 'img/busy.gif'
    document.getElementById('busyIndicator').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

the hideBusysign never is call, i try this but not work!

```
@Override
                public CharSequence getFailureHandler(Component component) {
                    return "document.getElementById('busyIndicator').style.display = 'none'; " +
" hideMask();";
```

Is that the correct way to implement a EnterKeypressEvent?

thanks, best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `'/ajax/call/beforeSend` instead of `'/ajax/call/before`.
`beforeSend` is executed only if all preconditions pass.